# What is the difference between class variables and function variables in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using props in react. And found this

```
var App = React.createClass({


        render: function(){
            var t = this.props.txt;
            return(<div>
                    <h1> {t}</h1>

                </div>);

        },

    });

    React.render(<App txt="hi"/>, document.body);
```

This works fine, as variable t is inside the render function. But when placed t outside the render function like this

```
var App = React.createClass({
// position of t is shifted here
    var t = this.props.txt;
        render: function(){

            return(<div>
                    <h1> {t}</h1>

                </div>);

        },

    });

    React.render(<App txt="hi"/>, document.body);
```

This does not work. Since I am invoking App directly in React.render not the function render, I expect that App should have props available. What am I missing?

Comment: App is a class right? I am instantiating class in render method. @FelixKling

Comment: Yeah, kind of. The last line is not the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure why you expect this to work. That's just invalid JavaScript. You cannot put a [variable declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) inside an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). Simplified example of what you are doing:

```
var foo = { var bar = 42; };
```

This is a syntax error. I recommend to [read a JavaScript tutorial to learn more about objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: var a ={
function v(){

var x =5;
}

}

Even this seems to be give an error

Comment: Well, similar reason: You cannot have a function declaration inside an object literal. The syntax of an object literals is `{key: value, key: value, ...}`. Check out the links.

Comment: So let's see, as you said App is an object and render is  a function. If a variable declaration inside App is invalid .I declared var t inside render. So it should be invalid too as we agreed

Comment: I didn't say that `App` is an object, but you are passing an object to `React.createClass`. And yes, `render` is a function. Honestly, I suggest to get a better understanding of JavaScript first before you take on React...

Comment: Please don't think bad, still you did not answer my question. How I am able to declare a variable inside a fucntion which is inside an object?. Yes, I don't know much Js. I have to pick that up

Comment: *"How I am able to declare a variable inside a fucntion which is inside an object?"* That's what the first example is doing. It declares `t` inside `render`. And I don't mean to sound harsh. It's just easier to pick up something (React) that builds on something else (JavaScript) if you are more familiar with it.

Comment: which should be invalid as per the above comments :(

Comment: Then you have misunderstood me at some point. The first example in your question is valid. It declares `t` inside the `render` function. The second example is invalid. You are trying to declare `t` inside the object literal but outside the function.

Comment: Got it, Thanks for clarification. You are helpful

Comment: Maybe you were referring to your first comment. The problem with `var a = { function v(){ var x =5; } }` is not the variable declaration but the function definition. You are not following the `{key: value}` pattern. You just wrote `{value}`. `var a = { b: function v(){ var x =5; } }` would be valid. And again, this has nothing to do with React. That's all JavaScript basics. Maybe you find this helpful as small introduction to a couple of important topics: http://felix-kling.de/jsbasics/

Comment: Yes, that's where I misunderstood. Thanks again for resources :)